# What algorithm is this?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I cannot seem to make sense of this particular algorithm. It seems to be a `bubblesort` but not in a traditional sense. What is it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double[] a = {0.75, 0.5, 1.0};                          
    sort(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
}

public static void sort(double[] tal)
{
    double p = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tal.length - 1; i++)
    {
        k = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < tal.length; j++)
        {
            if (tal[j] < tal[k])
                k = j;
        }

        p = tal[i];
        tal[i] = tal[k];
        tal[k] = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

At first, I incorrectly thought it an [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). It is a [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) (from the Wikipedia entry)

[image: Selection sort]

Comment: nice animation, but the OP algorithm is not an insertion sort.

Comment: Elliot, how did you make that animation?

Comment: @committedandroider It's from the linked wikipedia article. But, it's a fairly standard animated gif. I usually use gimp and [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) when I make one from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

It is a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The inner loop finds the smallest among the remaining elements which is then exchanged with the first element of the unsorted range.

Comment: Inline swaps are concidered being a bit faster then a using seperate swap method.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the claimed inefficiency? The code uses a local variable to store the index of the smallest element, and only does one swap for the next element. I'm not sure how you'll significantly improve on that.

Comment: @Dukeling On closer inspection you are right, I overlooked that the swaps are not happening in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) works with a `for`and a `while` loop.